# Connecting To FMS Server Issues

Tags: windows, firewall, tcp, connection, adobe

I am trying to get my computer to connect to an Adobe Connect server but I have had no luck. The error that Adobe is telling me is "ERROR: FMS Server did not return correctly!" and have done some narrowing down to figure out what the problem is...

- I know that its not a router issue because it still doesnt work when I bypass it, also Adobe Connect works fine on all my other computers in my network
- I have disabled the Windows Firewall (every which way) and that doesn't do anything
- It is something to do with trying to connect to port 1935 on the server because I can connect to port 80 fine but not port 1935
- I have a VirtualBox and Virtual PC network driver installed and I disabled those with no success
- I had used a TCP optimizer and trying restoring the settings with no success
- The furthest the connection to port 1935 will go in netstat is to SYN_SENT so for some reason the server isn't sending a ACK back
- It doesn't work in Firefox, Chrome, or Internet Explorer (Yes, I made sure SSL and TLS are enabled)

I am wondering if this might be some sort of firewall problem but the thing is, I have Windows Firewall totally disabled and there are no other firewalls (that I know of) running. I thought this might be because I had Norton 360 installed but that wasn't the problem. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**:

Here is the traceroute and nmap scan from the computer that **CAN** connect:

```
Tracing route to connect.bowvalleycollege.ca [199.185.132.114] 
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     1 ms     1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.1.1
  2    36 ms    36 ms    37 ms  d198-53-240-1.abhsia.telus.net [198.53.240.1]
  3    44 ms    39 ms    38 ms  173.182.202.193
  4    36 ms    36 ms    36 ms  CLGRAB31GR01.bb.telus.com [154.11.10.170]
  5    37 ms    35 ms    37 ms  154.11.2.218
  6    49 ms    48 ms    48 ms  core4-calgaryqa_gi6-0-0.net.bell.ca [64.230.77.252]
  7    50 ms    50 ms    58 ms  core4-calgary68_ge5-1-0.net.bell.ca [64.230.77.222]
  8    48 ms    50 ms    48 ms  core4-vancouver_pos11-1-0.net.bell.ca [64.230.77.207]
  9    48 ms    49 ms    48 ms  core1-vancouver_pos0-2-0.net.bell.ca [64.230.183.33]
 10    49 ms    86 ms    48 ms  bx2-vancouver_POS1-0.net.bell.ca [64.230.248.58]

 11    99 ms    49 ms    48 ms  204.101.4.90
 12    53 ms    51 ms    52 ms  static-67-226-180-101.ptr.terago.net [67.226.180.101]
 13    52 ms    53 ms    53 ms  static-67-226-180-142.ptr.terago.net [67.226.180.142]
 14     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 15    53 ms    51 ms    51 ms  reddog.bowvalleycollege.ca [199.185.132.4]
 16    53 ms    53 ms    53 ms  vpn.bowvalleycollege.ca [199.185.132.9]
 17     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 18     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 19     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 20     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 21     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 22     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 23     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 24     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 25     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 26     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 27     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 28     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 29     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 30     *        *        *     Request timed out.

Trace complete.

Starting Nmap 6.01 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2012-09-29 12:14 Mountain Daylight Time
Nmap scan report for connect.bowvalleycollege.ca (199.185.132.114)
Host is up (0.057s latency).
Not shown: 995 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
80/tcp   open   http
113/tcp  closed ident
443/tcp  closed https
1433/tcp open   ms-sql-s
1935/tcp open   rtmp

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 13.23 seconds
```

Here is the traceroute and nmap scan from the computer that **CANT** connect:

```
Tracing route to connect.bowvalleycollege.ca [199.185.132.114]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.1.1
  2    38 ms    35 ms    36 ms  d198-53-240-1.abhsia.telus.net [198.53.240.1]
  3    42 ms    37 ms    37 ms  173.182.202.193
  4    37 ms    37 ms    37 ms  CLGRAB31GR01.bb.telus.com [154.11.10.170]
  5    37 ms    37 ms    37 ms  154.11.2.218
  6    48 ms    48 ms    48 ms  core4-calgaryqa_gi6-0-0.net.bell.ca [64.230.77.252]
  7    48 ms    47 ms    48 ms  core4-calgary68_ge5-1-0.net.bell.ca [64.230.77.222]
  8    49 ms    48 ms    48 ms  core4-vancouver_pos11-1-0.net.bell.ca [64.230.77.207]
  9    48 ms    48 ms    48 ms  core1-vancouver_pos0-2-0.net.bell.ca [64.230.183.33]
 10    47 ms    48 ms    47 ms  bx2-vancouver_POS1-0.net.bell.ca [64.230.248.58]

 11    47 ms    48 ms    46 ms  204.101.4.90
 12    51 ms    52 ms    52 ms  static-67-226-180-101.ptr.terago.net [67.226.180.101]
 13    51 ms    52 ms    52 ms  static-67-226-180-142.ptr.terago.net [67.226.180.142]
 14     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 15    50 ms    49 ms    50 ms  reddog.bowvalleycollege.ca [199.185.132.4]
 16    52 ms    52 ms    52 ms  vpn.bowvalleycollege.ca [199.185.132.9]
 17     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 18     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 19     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 20     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 21     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 22     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 23     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 24     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 25     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 26     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 27     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 28     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 29     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 30     *        *        *     Request timed out.

Trace complete.

Starting Nmap 6.01 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2012-09-29 12:27 Mountain Daylight Time
Nmap scan report for connect.bowvalleycollege.ca (199.185.132.114)
Host is up (0.054s latency).
Not shown: 995 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
80/tcp   open   http
113/tcp  closed ident
443/tcp  closed https
1433/tcp open   ms-sql-s
1935/tcp open   rtmp

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 18.50 seconds
```

I think you will see by comparing these scans that they are the same. I have no control over `connect.bowvalleycollege.ca` so whatever the problem is should be able to be fixed on my end.

Comment: When you say you disabled Windows Firewall, is that on your machine or on the machine hosting the Adobe Connect server?

Comment: Port 1935 is absolutely required since RTMP protocol uses it to send media.

Comment: @Colin'tHart Its on my (the client) machine. I should also note that I don't have access to the server so I can't do much about that, however I am able to connect on my other machines so the servers not the problem.

Comment: Can you tracert to the server from both a machine that can and can't connect and see if there's any difference? Also, can you run nmap against the server, again from both a machine that can and can't connect and see if there's any difference? I'm wondering if there's another firewall between you can the server that's behaving differently for you than for other clients? Are you in a different subnet perhaps? This can be the case in some organizations where network security is implemented depending on your role in the organization.

Comment: @Colin'tHart I have added the traceroute and nmap scans to the question above.

Comment: Can you examine the firewall configuration on 192.168.1.1?

Comment: And what are the differences, if any, between the machine that can and the machine that can't connect?

Comment: @Colin'tHart Nothing that I can think of. They are both running Windows 7 (x64), On the same network, Using Windows Firewall + MS Security Essentials, The HOSTS files are the same, and There is no port forwarding setup so thats no different.
The only difference in terms of networking hardware, is the one that doesn't connect is wired and the ones that do are wireless. If you'd like I can send you a HijackThis! scan from both computers to compare the software?

Comment: Then there is a difference. Can you connect one of the normally wireless machines to the wired network and see if then that machine also can't connect?

Comment: I disconnected the PC that can connect (my laptop) from the wireless and connected it through the Ethernet cable and it still works. Any other ideas?

Comment: Verify that the port or open on your company by using this tool; http://www.therealtimeweb.com/index.cfm/2004/10/2/fms-port-tester If the tool reports the ports open, then it is not your company rather an intermediate network or the server. It there is an option to use RTMPT rather than RTMP use it, it will tunnel RTMP over port 80.

Comment: It is saying port 1935 failed for both RMTP and RMTPT??

Comment: Then something between your computer and the internet is blocking those ports. Since you have disabled the computer's firewall, it is probably your LAN's firewall or ACLs. How do you connect to the internet, DSL, corporate / college LAN, etc?

Comment: I am with TELUS so it is through a DSL modem which connects to my router. I know its nothing to do with the routers firewall because I tried connecting straight to the DSL modem and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few months of not being able to connect, I tried again one day to connect and it worked no problem. I'm guessing the problem was something to do with Adobe Connect because it was updated a few days before. I seem to recall trying to contact Adobe about this issue and they said it was something to do with my computer or network configuration.